# Setting an IFrame's height to 100% doesn't result in it expanding to fill the page?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to show an iframe and have it fill the full page. To do this, I'm using:

```
<iframe src="http://cnn.com" style="margin-top: 80px;" height="100%" width="100%" ></iframe>
```

There are no external stylesheets or anything, its simply a barebones html page which is showing this iframe.

However, while this does get the iframe to fill 100% of the with of the page (i.e it expands horizontally to full width), the iframe remains about 300-400px long vertically. Obviously that isn't enough to show the full page, so it gets a vertical scrollbar.

If I set the height to 1000px or 1500px, then it does work, but I would prefer to use percentages, so it would be neither too big, nor too small.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the height of the `html` and `body` tags to 100%:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```